# $\lim_{n\to \infty}n\left(e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Is it possible to find below limit
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\left(e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\right)$$
I am in doubt with this limit , because definition of $e=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$   is it true that $answer=0 $ ?

Am I right ?
   I am thankful if make a clarification .

Comment: Well, the answer is zero, but it is not enough to know that $x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k$ to show that $n\left(x-\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k\right)\to 0$.

Comment: For instance, $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(0-\frac1n)$ is $-1$, even though $0$ is the limit of $\frac1n$ (while if you use $\frac1{n^2}$ instead of $\frac1n$, the limit is $0$, and if you use $\frac1{\sqrt n}$ the limit is $-\infty$). Swap out $0$ with $e$ and $\frac1n$ with $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$, and there is no reason it should automatically be $0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $$n\left(e - \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\right) = \sum\limits_{k = {n+1}}^\infty \frac{n}{k!} = \sum_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\frac{n}{k} \leq\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-1)!}= \sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \to 0 .$$

Answer (score 2):

One can just use Cesaro-Stolz to get the desired limit as $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/(n+1)!}{1/n-1/(n+1)}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get a more precise estimate on $e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$.

$$e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1(1-t)^ne^{t}dt=\frac{e}{n!}\int_0^1 t^ne^{-t}dt$$

Note that $\int_0^1 t^ne^{-t}dt=\frac{e^{-1}}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1t^{n+1}e^{-t}dt=\frac{e^{-1}}{n+1}+o\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$, hence

$$e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+o\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\right)$$